# Prove that $7\nmid 2^{2k-1}+2^k+1$, for each $k\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Prove that $7\nmid 2^{2k-1}+2^k+1$, for each $k\in \mathbb{N}$

Here is a problem. Can we write: if $k\equiv _3 0$ then 
$$2^{2k-1}+2^k+1 \equiv _7 2^2+2^0+1?$$
That is what one of my students did. I'm a little uncomfortable with this kind of writing but I didn't have a proper argument against this record. Am I right or not?

Comment: Your student wanted, apparently, to check what happens with exponents divisible by three. Fine with that...yet I still don't understand how that helps him to prove the claim. His logic is sound, though: the multiplicative order of $\;2\pmod 7\;$ is three...

Comment: Well, then he did it for $k\equiv _3 1,2$ also...

Comment: If he exhausted all the cases and proved each correctly, then he's right...

Comment: So it doesn't matter if he used modular arithmetic with different modulus in the base and in the exponent at the same time?

Comment: Well, I can't be sure what he did...and perhaps you aren't, either. But there's something to **point** here. For example, he should point that $\;2^{3k}=1\pmod 7\;$ *no matter what* $\;k\in\Bbb N\;$ *you take*, and the same goes for $\;2^{3k+1}=2\pmod 7\;$ and etc. This is due to the fact that $\;2^3=1\pmod 7\;$, as comment before. It is up to you to decide how to grade what he argued... if he argued anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me, since $a\equiv b \bmod 3 \implies 2^a\equiv 2^b \bmod7$ . The full set of cases would be:

$\begin{align}
k\equiv_3 0 : && 2^{2k-1}+2^k+1 \equiv _7 2^2+2^0+1 =6 \not\equiv_7 0\\[1ex]
k\equiv_3 1 : &&  2^{2k-1}+2^k+1 \equiv _7 2^1+2^1+1 =5 \not\equiv_7 0\\[1ex]
k\equiv_3 2 : &&  2^{2k-1}+2^k+1 \equiv _7 2^0+2^2+1 =6 \not\equiv_7 0
\end{align}$

Comment: Without writing and proving the first sentence it would be doubtful solution?

Comment: @John At least I'd ask him : can you explain or justify, as done in your paper, why for example  $\;2^4=2^7=...=2^{3k+1}=2\pmod 7\;$ ? Otherwise it is weird to use modulo $\;3\;$ for the exponents...and, of course, unacceptable to do so *without full explanation*

Comment: Yes - I don't know that you need to prove it exactly, but you should at least state it.

Comment: @JohnWatson ... or if needed the simple observation that $2^3\equiv 1 \bmod 7$ bridges the gap reasonably well.

Answer (score 4):

I'd try the following: put $\;x:=2^k\;$ , so that we get

$$2^{2k-1}+2^k+1=\frac12x^2+x+1=_7=4x^2+x+1$$

the last quadratic's discriminant is $\;\Delta=1-16=-15=-1\;$ , and since $\;7=3\pmod4\;$ the quadratic has no roots $\;\mod 7\;$ , which means the original expression can't equal $\;0\pmod 7\;$ ... Fill in details.

Comment: Beautiful solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variant on DonAntonio's answer:

If you know about quadratic residues, then

$$7\mid(2^{2k-1}+2^k+1)\implies7\mid(2^{2k}+2\cdot2^k+2)\implies7\mid(2^k+1)^2+1\implies\left(-1\over7\right)=1$$

which is a contradiction to the "well known" value $\left(-1\over7\right)=-1$.

If you don't yet know about quadratic residues, all you have to do is note that $7\mid(2^k+1)^2+1$ implies $-1$ is a square mod $7$ (namely $-1\equiv(2^k+1)^2$ mod $7$) and then check that $0^2$, $(\pm1)^2$, $(\pm2)^2$, and $(\pm3)^2$ mod $7$ are all different from $-1$.